# How to run Joomla with local webserver like desktop software/.exe file?

Tags: joomla-3.x, module-display

How to run Joomla like desktop software/.exe file?
I want to use Joomla to make a medical software like MKSAP and SESAP.

Is it possible to pack and run Joomla with local server from .iso like a desktop software? Please provide links to tutorials. Thank you.

Comment: PHP is a server side language, therefore if on your localhost, the user would need to have Wamp, Mamp, Xampp or Lamp installed. I'm not sure what the technical term in software is, but you would be best off using an iframe wrapper to show your Joomla site from an online source

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it *is* possible to run a local web server from a portable media, even write-protected media like CD and DVD.

There are several alternatives, both free and commercial, but you have to check if the specifications are compatible with Joomla.

- [Server2Go](http://www.server2go-web.de/) (free)
- [DWebPro](http://www.dwebpro.com/download) (free for non-commercial use). Tutorials for several common web applications can be found [here](http://www.dwebpro.com/howto).
- [Stunnix Advanced Web server](http://stunnix.com/prod/aws/overview.shtml) (commercial).
- XAMPP lite - probably won't work on read-only devices like CD and DVD, but a tutorial can be found [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14998/turn-your-flash-drive-into-a-portable-web-server/).

As for user-friendliness of such an application, I'm not entirely convinced. Why not create an .exe-file that opens the browser with your live site, or wrap it in an iframe inside your software, as @Lodder suggested? It would probably be easier to use and to update, unless you need to use this somewhere without an internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

Only self-executable solution I heard of is Joomlas2Go! http://www.joomlas2go.net/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with NuSphere's PhpDock. PhpDock enables you to deploy any PHP web application as a Stand Alone Windows Desktop application w/o any changes in the code. http://www.nusphere.com/products/phpdock.htm